# How can i pass validated data to another custom validator class in DRF?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I Have this kind of serializer.py

```
class PostSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    title = serializers.CharField(validators=[TitleValidator()])
    slug = serializers.CharField(validators=[SlugsValidator()], max_length=100, required=False)
```

and i have two class validators for this fields

```
class TitleValidator:
    
    MIN_TITLE_LENGTH = 20
    
    def __call__(self, title: str):
        if len(title) < self.MIN_TITLE_LENGTH:
            raise ValidationError(f"Min title length is {self.MIN_TITLE_LENGTH}")
        return title


class SlugsValidator:

    def __call__(self, slug):
        # Get title here
        return slug
```

How can I pass the validated title into `SlugValidator` class?

I've tried to pass data directly to the `TitleValidator` instance, but the only thing I can get is the field itself, not an actual value.
Another way was to pass data inside validate() method, but seems like custom class validators are executed first, and i' getting an error that the title argument is not provided.
Is there any way I can achieve this?

It seems like it possible to get all fields if you define all class validators inside `Meta` class, but I'm wondering if it is possible without using `Meta` class